# Find property name from value in jscript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a property name if I know value from object defined as

```
expOperators = {
    "0": "Select operator",
    "GREATERTHAN": "After",
    "LESSTHAN": "Before",
    "GREATERTHANEQUALTO": "On or After",
    "LESSTHANEQUALTO": "On or Before",
    "EQUALS": "On",
    "BETWEEN": "Between",
    "ISNULL": "Is Null",
    "ISNOTNULL": "Is not Null"
};
```

Obviously if I need to find value it would be easy, but I need to accomplish an opposite task, knowing value find out what is the property. Any idea?

Comment: I can't help but think there may be a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have too loop through the object and compare the object values to what you're looking for.

```
expOperators = {
    "0": "Select operator",
    "GREATERTHAN": "After",
    "LESSTHAN": "Before",
    "GREATERTHANEQUALTO": "On or After",
    "LESSTHANEQUALTO": "On or Before",
    "EQUALS": "On",
    "BETWEEN": "Between",
    "ISNULL": "Is Null",
    "ISNOTNULL": "Is not Null"
};

for(var name in expOperators ) {
    if(expOperators[name] === "Between"){
        document.write(name);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WsjyS/2/

Comment: consider including `hasOwnProperty` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
 for(var name in expOperators ) {
    if(expOperators.hasOwnProperty(name)){
      if(expOperators[name] === "Between"){
         alert(name);
       }
    }
}
```